# Why didn't individual box plots draw for each factor by geom_box?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, boxplot

I have an issue with plotting violin plot along with box plot, which will show descriptive statistics  for my data sample.
I have a data with 3 columns with variables: channel , Year , durationMins , with 20 observations.

This is my code:

I want to build a violin plot with a box plot in ShinyApp.

```
#Simulate Data for Reproducible Code
# Set the number of observations
{n <- 512

# Define channel names
channels <- c("Channel_A", "Channel_B", "Channel_C", "Channel_D")

# Define months and days of the week
months <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
days <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")

# Create a data frame to store the data
df1 <- data.frame()

# Generate data for each channel
for (channel in channels) {
  # Generate data for each year
  for (year in 2017:2024) {
    # Generate data for each month
    for (month in months) {
      # Sample durations for each day of the month
      for (day in 1:30) {  # Assuming 30 days per month
        # Sample duration for the specific channel, year, month, and day
        durations <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 4.59, max = 30.7), 1)
        # Sample a random day of the week
        day_of_week <- sample(days, 1)
        # Append the data to the data frame
        df1 <- rbind(df1, data.frame(channel = channel, Year = year, Month = month, Day = day, publishedDayName = day_of_week, durationMins = durations))
      }
    }
  }
}

# Randomly shuffle the rows of the data frame
df1 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1)), ]}

# View the first few rows of the data frame
head(df1)

#ShinyApp
ui<-
  fluidPage(
    tags$script(HTML('$(document).ready(function() {
        // Get the position of the sidebar
        var sidebarPosition = $(".sidebar").offset().top;

        // Function to fix or unfix the sidebar based on scrolling
        function fixSidebar() {
          var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

          if (scrollTop > sidebarPosition) {
            $(".sidebar").addClass("fixed-sidebar");
          } else {
            $(".sidebar").removeClass("fixed-sidebar");
          }
        }

        // Attach the function to the scroll event
        $(window).scroll(fixSidebar);

        // Call the function once to set the initial state
        fixSidebar();
      });
    ')),
  
    titlePanel("Youtube Data science Channels Videon Duration Analytics"),
    mainPanel(plotOutput('dur_Plot'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(lubridate)
  
  #Duration plot
  duration_pipeline_f <- reactive({
    df1 %>% 
      group_by(channel, Year) %>%
      summarize(durationMins = mean(durationMins))%>% 
      arrange(Year, .by_group = T) 
  })
  
  output$dur_Plot  <-renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(duration_pipeline_f(), aes(x = Year, y = durationMins, fill = channel)) +
      geom_violin(position = 'dodge', trim = FALSE, linewidth = .5, alpha = .9) +
      geom_boxplot(width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), fill = 'white', color = 'black') +
      labs(title = 'Video duration distribution', y = 'Duration in mins') +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Spectral') + 
      theme(text = element_text(size = 12))
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this code in server part I've filtered data that's why I have less observations than in a raw sample. Maybe this simulation will help you to understand my issue.

[This is the view of my shinyApp page with a mentioned plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGlen.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. As is we can't reproduce your issue as we can't run your code.

Comment: @stefan is right. Provide the UI and the data please. Also, does it work outside Shiny? And what is the issue more precisely?

Comment: @stefan I have listened to your point and add simulated data to play with the mentioned code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your question has nothing to do with shiny and would have been easier solved by focusing on the `ggplot2` code.

The issue is simply the grouping. First,m your violin plots are implicitly grouped by `channel` as you map on `fill` whereas for the box plots you override the grouping by setting `fill="white"`. hence, for the boxplotz you have to explicitly map on the `group` aes. Moreover, as your `Year` variable is a numeric you get violin (and/or box plots) showing the distribution over all years. And as you mapped `Year` on `x` you probably want violin/box plots for each year. In that case you have to convert `Year` to a `factor` or group explicitly by `Year` too as I do below.

Note: I used the non-aggregated data set as IMHO it makes no sense to aggregate a dataset if you want to show the distribution.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  duration_pipeline_f <- reactive({
    df1
  })

  output$dur_Plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(duration_pipeline_f(), aes(
      x = Year, 
      y = durationMins,
      fill = channel,
      group = interaction(Year, channel)
    )) +
      geom_violin(
        position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
        trim = FALSE,
        linewidth = .5, alpha = .9
      ) +
      geom_boxplot(
        aes(group = interaction(Year, channel)),
        width = 0.7,
        position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
        fill = "white", color = "black"
      ) +
      labs(title = "Video duration distribution", y = "Duration in mins") +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
      theme(text = element_text(size = 12))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6007
```

[image]